# Running selenium standalone jar file automatically through code?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While running scripts in Remote machine we need to run the Selenium Stand alone server jar file in the remote machine manually. Is there any way to integrate some code in the script so that the jar file will run automatically in the remote machine?

If anyone have done this scenario can share the code how to do this?

Thanks,

SUdhansu

Comment: This [link](http://www.testingexcellence.com/how-to-start-selenium-server-with-java-code/) could help. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell may be perfect solution for your issue. Follow this link to configure powershell in your machine as well as remote machine.
http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

After this, add script to run this jar file on remote machine. For java you can do-
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ComputerName "REMOTE-COMPUTER-NAME" -ScriptBlock { java -jar \path\to\selenium-standalone.jar } -credential username-of-remote");

It will prompt you for password of remote machine. Give that and your jar file will be run on remote machine.

Hope this will help you.